# ASP.NET Core 1.1 can't Publish App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run a simple `dotnet publish` command so I can compile my web application on my linux server. It tells me that my `project.json` is missing.

Before you answer, there have been some recent changes below you should consider. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't need `project.json` because my web application is a higher version that doesn't require it:

> I'm currently running on ASP.NET Core 1.1 and .NET Core 1.1. As I am
>   aware in November 2016 they depreciated `project.json` in favor of
>   `project.csproj` so projects created in Visual Studio 2017 will no longer generate
>   this file any longer.
>
> ---
>
> ASP.NET Core 1.0 uses `project.json`
>   ASP.NET Core 1.1 uses `project.csproj`

How I created my web application project:

- Visual Studio 2017 RC
- ASP.NET Core 1.1 (web application)
- .NET Core 1.1

> I only displayed how I created my project because it shows people I
>   don't need to `dotnet migrate` into 1.1 since the project never begun
>   as a 1.0 project

Locally my project runs fine, it `restores`, it `publishes` it `runs`. It does all the fun things `dotnet` commands should do perfectly fine.

**The more specific question**:
On a linux server with the latest `dotnet --version` running `dotnet publish` gives me the error saying `project.json` is required. Why does the latest version of .NET Core (1.1) require `project.json` when clearly its depreciated in version 1.1 and should be looking for `.csproj` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we're in this crossover period where `project.json` is being replaced by `.csproj`, there are two versions of the SDK. There is still a version of the SDK based around `project.json` for v1.1, and you must have that installed on your linux server.

This mess should be going away very soon (with the release of VS2017 in roughly a week's time) when the tooling goes to RTM. From that point onwards everything will be `.csproj` based and `project.json` is fully deprecated.

Comment: Ah, the transitional period between versions. To be honest, at glance the project.json file looks more readable and organized than the project.csproj but that is just my opinion. Thanks for the information.

Comment: The justification is that all of .NET sharing the a single build process and tooling brings manifold benefits in terms of lowered complexity, surface area, and duplication. It's a shame that `project.json` couldn't be the winning horse (I and most people I've spoken to agree with you that JSON > XML), but as I understand it there is simply too much inertia on the MSBuild side of things for it to get replaced or rebuilt in any reasonable time frame.